# in C++: Is const reference means "read-only view of" or it requires immutability of object being referenced?

Tags: c++

The question can be formulated by example as following: is this snippet of code valid?

```
int a = 1;
const int& ca = a;
++a; //< Q: Is this valid?
cout << "a: " << a << endl;
cout << "ca: " << ca << endl; // Q: Is it guaranteed to output "2"? Is it valid at all?
```

With MSVC and MinGW the snippet above works as expected: if I query `ca` afterwords, it returns `2` (i.e. it was changed by non-const reference). But the question is: how this situation considered from the point of view of standard? Is it OK, that we change object, to which we have const reference (or e.g. we must define `ca` to be const volatile reference for the snippet to be correct)?

So, if snippet above is correct, then it means, that const reference does not guarantee, that referenced object is constant. It only prohibits us to change it via the given reference, i.e. establishes "read-only" view of referenced object. Is this correct?

**Edit:**
Thanks for everyone who answered my question. The answers state the thing, which seems natural for me. However I would really appreciate is someone give reference to specific clause in the c++ standard.

**Edit2:**
Original example was extended to make idea of the question more clear.

**Edit3**
Another example, which originally appeared in my comment to the answer of Mats Peterson.

```
class MyClass {
public:
    // ...
    const X& getX() const;
    void modifyX();
private:
    X m_x;
};

void someFun() {
    //...
    MyClass myObj = ... // non-cons
    const X& x = myObj.getX();
    // ...
    myObj.modifyX(); // Q: is `x` guaranteed to track value of x stored in myObj here?
}
```

And the question is: Is it allowed to compiler during optimization to remove updates of `x` variable, as it is declared `const`? E.g. if type `X` is `bool`, then storing `x` by value provides better performance and less memory consumption than storage by reference.

Putting it in another words: is it guaranteed, that local variable `x` will track changes of corresponding internal value inside `myObj` if subsequent calls to methods of `myObj` modify that internal value?

Comment: "It means, that const reference does not guarantee, that referenced object is constant. It only prohibits us to change it via the given reference, i.e. establishes "read-only" view of referenced object"

Comment: This is still quite different from the example in the comment to my answer. And there are some possible scenarios where it's extremely complicated to figure out exactly what goes on.

Comment: I would say it's definitely legal to modify `a` in the above code.

Comment: I remember having a wierd feeling having to synchronize reads from a const reference. I know casting away const is UB only if the object referred to by the ref was origionally declared const.

Answer (score 5):

It is valid code, because `a` is  not `const`. A `const` reference means you cannot modify the refered-to object via the reference.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, all you are doing is creating a REFERENCE that is `const` - meaning that `ca` can't modify the value it refers to (`a` in this case).

A common usage is to pass a const reference to a function:

```
void foo(const int& cr)
{
   ... use cr ... 
}
```

This indicates that although the value is a reference, the function `foo` does not alter the value in `cr`. It is perfectly valid to call this function with a modifiable `int` variable, or even something that can't be referenced (for example `foo(4);` - the value 4 is just a constant, so can't really be used as a reference - the compiler will "fix" this by creating a temporary int variable, and pass the reference to that).

Of course, this is more commonly used with more complex types than `int` - for example `std::string` or `std::vector`. The main reason in this case is to avoid the value being copied, rather than "I want a reference".

Comment: More relevant would be analysts of following example: `const X& x = myObj.getConstX(); myObj.modifyX();`. And the question is: Is it guaranteed, that local `x` tracks changes of corresponding internal data of `myObj`? Of course `mhObj` is not const.

Comment: Hmm, that is a completely different question, and probably should really be asked as a separate question. I don't know if the standard specifies that. One can easily see that if it's not required by the standard, that a compiler could optimise out reads of `x` and just use a previously read value.

Comment: Yes, exactly. This is not another question, - this is exactly the question, which I was asking from the very beginning. Though, now I understand, that my original example does not highlight the main idea clearly. I will try to fix it.

Comment: A very simple test using g++ 4.6.3 and clang++ shows that these things do not appear to get optimised out. In other words, the changes inside the object does change the actual value in the reference. Which is what you'd expect, at least kind of.

Comment: @DmitrySemikin: No, it _is_ a different question. :) A reference always "tracks" the referent precisely, but whether you get the correct result in two separate reads to the same object with a write in between that may not be visible in the current translation unit is a completely different issue (and not relevant to references themselves). Think `volatile`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

As a reference is just *another name* to a variable and not the object itself, yes in the snippet you show it can be thought as a read-only reference. The code provided with the reference can only access it but it does not guarantee that the object itself won't be changed in another place of your program.