# Confusion about `const` in compound assignment

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, language-lawyer, const-correctness

The [canonical implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) of `operator+=` passes the RHS as a `const` reference:

```
X& operator+=(const X& rhs)
```

However, in

```
x += x;
```

the RHS *is* modified. Does this invoke the UB?

Comment: Why do you think there is UB here? `x` is modifiable. `rhs` is not, but it's not being modified.

Comment: How is `rhs` modified? Following your path of thinking, would `int a = 5; int const& ar = a; a = 6;` count as modifying `ar`?

Comment: The dupe seems not the right one:  X += X is UB because of the rule about side effets and undetermined sequencing.  The fact that rhs is read only or immutable doesn't play a role here

Comment: @Christophe - That rule only applies to built-in operators. An overloaded operator is a **function call**

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica can you be more specific with a quote

Comment: @Christophe - https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr#2

Comment: And since the question focuses on the const vs non-const aspect, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22436856/in-c-is-const-reference-means-read-only-view-of-or-it-requires-immutability is still a worthy duplicate candidate.

Comment: Note that in `x += x;`, there is both a left-hand `x` and a right-hand `x`; while the effects of modifying either one will be seen in both, this doesn't mean that modifying one is the same as modifying the other.

Comment: const reference doesn't mean that the object it refers to is const or cannot be changed .

Answer (score 5):

From [dcl.type.cv](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.cv#3):

> A pointer or reference to a cv-qualified type *need not actually* point or refer to a cv-qualified object, but it is treated as if it does; a const-qualified access path cannot be used to modify an object even if the object referenced is a non-const object and *can be modified through some other access path*.

The reference `rhs` is const qualified, so it cannot be used to modify the object it refers to.

However, the object being referenced, i.e. `x`, is non-const, and so `x` itself can be modified through other access paths, e.g. in the definition of `operator+=`.

So the behavior is well defined in this code sample.

Answer (score 2):

The `const` means that the reference is a reference to const and a reference to const can bind to a non-const object. Binding a reference to const to a non-const object doesn't make the object itself const. It just means that you can't modify the object through the reference to const, and if the object isn't const it can be modified in another way.

In this case, the reference is a reference to const, but the object referenced is not const, so modifying the object is fine.

Answer (score -1):

Let me provide another way of thinking it.

IIRC, `const` is only visible for debugging. It means you cannot modify a thing from this way, i.e. this name(**reference**). When you compile your program the compiler will drop them out after checking you done everything in right way.